# Rails Root Path Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I have following in my routes file:
    root :to=> "Registrations#index"
But when I go to the root path (localhost:3000), the default rails app page shows instead of the view for Registrations#index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the public/index.html in order for the route to work.